# Fabric and Jinja Template Uploading

Tags: python, fabric, jinja2

For some reason, Jinja claims that it is unable to find a template that I have specified in my Fabric task:

```
httpd_local = "/path/to/dir/conf/" # with httpd.conf located here
httpd_remote = "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

with lcd(httpd_local):
    upload_template(filename='/path/to/dir/conf/httpd.conf', destination=httpd_remote, context=context[hostname], use_jinja=True)
```

But every time I run, I get

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /path/to/dir/conf/httpd.conf
```

It definitely lives there though. What's going on?

Answer (score 5):

To clarify oselivanov's answer, this would be your example with the proper format:

```
httpd_local = "/path/to/dir/conf/" # with httpd.conf located here
httpd_remote = "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

with lcd(httpd_local):
    upload_template(filename='httpd.conf', destination=httpd_remote, template_dir='/path/to/dir/conf', context=context[hostname], use_jinja=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

From upload_template docstring:

> Alternately, if `use_jinja` is set to True and you have the Jinja2
>       templating library available, Jinja will be used to render the template
>       instead. Templates will be loaded from the invoking user's current working
>       directory by default, or from `template_dir` if given.

Сonfusing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a bug.

Check out: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/621